# How to convert panel into pdf with same font and style using iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net

I am using iTextSharp dll to convert panel in aspx page. Panel have controls like label, textboxes along with gridview and listview in it. The problem is this that after converting panel to pdf format i lost all the formatting of listview/gridview/other controls. I am using below code`

```
    string file = txtenqid.Text + ".pdf";
    string attachment = string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", file);
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    Panel1.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
   iTextSharp.text.Document pdfdoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
   pdfdoc.SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);

    pdfdoc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A3);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfdoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfdoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfdoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfdoc.Close();
```

please do  the needful changes in the code so that i got my desired result. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Formatting could be lost because the pdf generated may not be as wide as the panel itself. Try setting the pdf page size to A4 instead of A3

```
 iTextSharp.text.Document pdfdoc = new Document(new Rectangle(288f, 144f), 10, 10, 10, 10);
    pdfdoc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
```

Also rotating it to landscape may solve your issue

```
  pdfdoc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());
```

Comment: ths will change the page setting bt not resolve my issue of same font and style and gridview lost its auto formatting that i did in aspx page